# Turn light On at 08:30 WebIOPi raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, webiopi

for set hour_on | hour_off, there is in a configuration these command:

```
HOUR_ON  = 8  # Turn Light ON at 08:00
HOUR_OFF = 18 # Turn Light OFF at 18:00
```

And it's ok, but if I would set `HOUR_ON` at 08:30?

Comment: have you tried it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your sample program to add the functionality for minutes.
Please refer to [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#dates-and-times) for details on Python date manipulation.

[This page](http://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/raspberrypi-guide/raspberry-pi-webiopi-iot-part-3-programming-basics-inputoutput/) explains how to modify `loop` function to add `minutes` functionality,

```
def loop():
    # Get the current time
    now = datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now().hour, datetime.datetime.now().minute)

    # Automatically switch on LED
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_ON.hour) and (now.minute == HOUR_ON.minute) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(LIGHT) == GPIO.LOW):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(LIGHT, GPIO.HIGH)

    # Automatically switch off LED
    if ((now.hour == HOUR_OFF.hour) and (now.minute == HOUR_OFF.minute) and (now.second == 0)):
        if (GPIO.digitalRead(LIGHT) == GPIO.HIGH):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(LIGHT, GPIO.LOW)

    # Repeat every 1 second
    webiopi.sleep(1)
```